# Add a shadow to the Gallery items in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, shadow

In my app, i have a gallery of imageView, how can i add a shadow effect for each item, thanks in advance,
example [image: image with shadow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a background image and play around with 9-patch.

the background will contain the shadows. If you need more info about the 9-patch :

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: could you explain more please?

Comment: @Vervatovskis http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial you can see this for more details